# can we by pass the serialization process for jquery ajax call to amfphp server?

Tags: frameworks, amfphp

In my project, I am using flex, HTML5 and PHP. We need serialized object for Flex part. However, I don't want to serialized object for JQuery ajax call. Is there any way to skip serialize process to improve performance?

Basically, I need JSON Object for service returns

Answer (score 0):

If you send a JSON request you'll get a JSON response. That's how the Service Browser works. You just have to make sure Amfphp gets that's it JSON. That's either via the HTTP content type header or by adding a GET parameter. For example : "../Amfphp/index.php?contentType=application/json";